# How can l loop through json object by using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to loop through JSON object but l does not work, l want it to look structured. please help!!

how can l loop through this by using jquery? and putting it in a structure?

```
[
    {   "name": "Webredpizzan", 
        "price": 20, 
        "content":["Ost","Gorgonzola","Mozarella"], 
        "picture":"images/item3.jpg"
    },


    {
        "name": "IT-pizzan", 
        "price": 10, 
        "content":["Ost","Lamm","Kalkon"], 
        "picture":"images/item1.jpg"
    },
    {
        "name": "Bibliotekspizzan", 
        "price": 11, 
        "content":["Ost","Basilika","Mozarella"], 
        "picture":"images/item2.jpg"
    },
    {
        "name": "Frukt-pizzan", 
        "price": 20, 
        "content":["Banan","Blåbär","Äpple"], 
        "picture":"images/item3.jpg"
    }
]
```

l want to put it in this structure

```
<div class="pizza_details">
<img src="'+picture+'" />

<div class="desc">'
<ul> <li><span>Namn</span> : '+ name +'</li>
<li><span>Pris</span> : '+price;+'</li>
<li><span>Innehåll</span> : '+content+'</li>
</ul></div><div class="clear"></div> </div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You can try like this https://jsfiddle.net/fotnjtxc/

Comment: Thank  you  very much for helping but l  want to have a jquery code for this so l can put it in my javascript file. How can l do it, lam very  new to  this. please help!!

Comment: l did the same thing as you did but it didn't work nothing showed up on the page.